# How to programmatically break up strokes in fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

I am building a doodle app. Users basically draw, and it updates on the other users' screens. However, users are complaining that the app doesn't update mid-long stroke. Is there a way to break up users' long strokes after 1 second? someFunctionToBreakUpMaxLength() or prop that I can set?

```
_onMouseDown = e => {
    console.log('on mouse down fired');
    window.global.mouseDownStart = Date.now();
    const {onMouseDown} = this.props;
    this._selectedTool.doMouseDown(e);
    onMouseDown(e);
  };

_onMouseMove = e => {
    const timeDiff = window.global.mouseDownStart - Date.now();
    if (window.global.mouseDownStart && timeDiff < -1000) {
      console.log('mouse up fired, artifical', {
        mouseDownStart: window.global.mouseDownStart,
        now: Date.now(),
        diff: timeDiff,
      });
      someFunctionToBreakUpMaxLength()
    }
    // let onChange = this.props.onChange;
    // onChange(this._fc.toJSON());
    const {onMouseMove} = this.props;
    this._selectedTool.doMouseMove(e);
    onMouseMove(e);
  };
```